# Expand/collapse in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am currently making an accordion from data coming from a service (I have made an object named "groups" for example). Currently, I can click on the Group Name and it will hide/show the Description correctly, however it opens all instances. How can I make it open the group that was clicked, instead of all?

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ch609uov/1/

I know I can use the open property in my groups var, however the actual data I am working with does not have that property. So, I need it to work with the isExpanded prop which I have added to my Vue instance.

```
var groups = {
"GROUP A": {
"name": "GROUP A",
"open": false,
"desc": "description 1",
"heading": "test",
"items": [
  "item 1"
]
},

new Vue({
el: ".vue",
data: {
groups: groups,
heading: "Plan Communications",
isExpanded: false
}
})
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/ch609uov/2/

Comment: Thanks Derek, but the actual data that I have coming in does not have the 'open' prop. So I cannot tie into that. I will have to use the 'isExpanded' prop. Basically, pretend that 'open' prop is not available.

Comment: Is expanded is going to open all of them at once, which is undesirable. Each of them need their own unique identifier in order to work as you desire

Comment: Or maybe I can push a new prop to my groups var, then use it?

Comment: How can I give them each a unique identifier? Can I push a new prop to it and use that? The data in which I am working with comes from a service and I cannot alter it directly.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/ch609uov/4/

Comment: Yes! That is helpful. Seems like a lot of code for a simple expand/collapse. Wish it was more minimal, but this does the trick! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I will write an answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modifying the resource data locally

There are a few ways you can go about doing this, the first way actually modifies the data returned from the external resource in such a way that each entry has its own `open` attribute:

```js
let serviceDataExample = [{title: "some title 1"}, {title: "some title 2"}, {title: "some title 3"}];

serviceDataExample.forEach(obj => {
 obj.open = false;
});

console.log(serviceDataExample);

// assign to your data object with `this` and use the open 
// attribute individually in the template
```

In the above, `serviceDataExample` is just a mock representation of what the data might look like.

The downside to the solution above is that every time you fetch new data from the resource, you're going to have to essentially re-run the `forEach` before assigning it to your data object.

---

#### Without modifying the resource data locally

Doing it this way ensures that you never have to clutter the original (local) resource data with display settings:

```js
var groups = {
  "GROUP A": {
    "name": "GROUP A",
    "open": false,
    "desc": "description 1",
    "heading": "test",
    "items": [
      "item 1"
    ]
  },
  "GROUP B": {
    "name": "GROUP B",
    "open": false,
    "desc": "description 2",
    "items": [
      "item 1",
      "item 2",
      "item 3",
      "item 4",
      "item 5",
      "item 6",
      "item 7"
    ]
  },
  "GROUP C": {
    "name": "GROUP C",
    "open": false,
    "desc": "description 3",
    "items": [
      "item 1",
      "item 2",
      "item 3",
      "item 4",
      "item 5"
    ]
  },
  "GROUP D": {
    "name": "GROUP D",
    "open": false,
    "desc": "description 4",
    "items": [
      "item 1",
      "item 2",
      "item 3",
      "item 4",
      "item 5",
      "item 6",
      "item 7"
    ]
  },
  "GROUP E": {
    "name": "GROUP E",
    "open": false,
    "desc": "description 5",
    "items": [
      "item 1",
      "item 2",
      "item 3",
      "item 4",
      "item 5"
    ]
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: ".vue",
  data: {
    groups: groups,
    heading: "Plan Communications",
    // isExpanded: false,
    expandedGroup: []
  },
  methods: {
    isExpanded(key) {
     return this.expandedGroup.indexOf(key) !== -1;
    },
    toggleExpansion(key) {
     if (this.isExpanded(key))
           this.expandedGroup.splice(this.expandedGroup.indexOf(key), 1);
        else
           this.expandedGroup.push(key);
    }
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container vue">
    <div v-for="(group, key) in groups"> 
    <a @click="toggleExpansion(key)" >{{group.name}}</a>
    <ul v-show="isExpanded(key)">
      <li>{{group.desc}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, we are creating an external data attribute in order to keep track of the *index* of the group that is expanded. If the `group`'s index exists within the local `expandedGroup`, then it is open, if not, it is closed.

Hope this helps!